# Google Chrome bug with tr background

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to set a background-image to a table row, but background is applied to all its td children.

In IE7 there is the same bug but it is solve with

```
tr {
    position: relative;
}
```

Any hint about it ?

Thank you

Comment: WebKit does the same (as does Opera in quirks mode). And the IE fix also needs `td { background-image: none; }` or IE will merrily render the image again in each cell content area. Really, this has never been reliable cross-browser, and I'm not sure the side-effects of hacks like the relative-positioning are something you should rely on. Find another approach?

Comment: My answer is being deleted by the mods, but I'll comment it here, use: background-attachment: fixed;

Answer (score 12):

This works for me in all browsers:

```
tr {
background: transparent url(/shadow-down.gif) no-repeat 0% 100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 828px;
}

tr td{
background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: when I changed my tr to display: block... it lost all the column formatting (i.e. the rows no longer lined up with the headings). How do you resolve that?

Comment: This didn't work for me in chrome - it caused the entire row to take up one column of the table and the other rows to get bumped to the right of the table.

Comment: You might need explicit widths on each td.

Comment: adding display:block to the TR basically transforms it into a DIV, that's why it works... hewitt is right, you will need to set up widths for your TDs, you can use percentage.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I set up column width, yet the layout is broken.

Comment: works fine ... you just need to format td's too, set height and width to every td child and it should be fine (tested in IE7,8,9 and 10, FF, Chrome, Opera)

I am a bit confused that even 3 years after this post bug still exist in chrome

Answer (score 5):

In tr style tag include `Style='Display:inline-table;'` It works fine in all browser.

Comment: This works great, it's like the display:block fix but it renders better, looks more like the original table would. Tested on Chrome

Comment: This works for me. Tested on Chrome, FF and IE. I applied the code via stylesheet: `tr{display:inline-table';}`

Answer (score 3):

Chrome (WebKit) overrides the position:relative for table rows and calculates the style to static. Bug or feature - this prevents the position:relative fix as is used in IE7.

Solution when using fixed (known) cell sizes:
**tr** {
    **float**:*left*;
}

And add appropriate cell sizes to all cells in the table (either via class or inline styles). I had also added row sizes, however it might not be required for the solution to work.

I have no need for a solution for dynamic cell sizes, so I haven't been exploring that usecase.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was:

```
table.money-list tr {
background: url(images/status-2.gif) no-repeat;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    /*Chrome CSS here*/
    table tbody tr td:first-child {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

table tr td{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
}
```

So as you can see, just set a background color to every TD but the first one, and target Webkit.

Answer (score 1):

None of the workarounds mentioned worked for me quite right. Here's what I ended up with:

```css
TABLE TBODY.highlight {
    background-image: url(path/image.png);
}

TABLE>* {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Only tested in Chrome and Firefox so no idea how it works in IE (not important in my case), but for me this works flawlessly!

Comment: Not a viable solution as the float left broke the table, but the idea to apply the background to the tbody instead of the table row was genius.  Add in the fact that a `<table>` can have more than one `<tbody>` and we are in business.

Answer (score 1):

Spent two days on this problem, finally found the answer here:

You need to set:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Not sure why the mods are deleting this answer, its not on the page.

Comment: This answer fixed my problem, which was a css3 repeating-linear-gradient on a `tr` resetting itself in every `td` in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution I am aware of without using JavaScript. It has the shortcoming of you specifying the height of the TR and the TD, because the TR is positioned absolute. I am also not sure how it will behave in other browsers.

```
<style>
    tr {
        position: absolute;
        background: url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif) no-repeat;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #00f;
    }
    td {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #f00;
    }
</style>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to set the background-image for the table-cells directly, shifting the background-position of all subsequent cells to the left so that it looks as it should. This way you don't have to slice your background-image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my jQuery solution. It's for a thead tr but should work for tbody tr's as well.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // Apply <thead><tr> background row fix for Chrome/Safari (webkit)
    if ($.browser.webkit) {
        $('thead tr').each(function (i) {
            var theadWidth = $(this).width()-1;
            $(this).append('<div style="position:absolute;top:'+$(this).position().top+'px;left:'+$(this).position().left+'px;z-index:0;width:'+theadWidth+'px;height:'+($(this).height()+8)+'px;background:#2e4b83 url(th_background.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;background-size:'+theadWidth+'px 100%;"></div>');
        });
    }
});
```

You can check it out in Chrome/Firefox/IE9. It should appear the same.

Answer (score 0):

It should fix the `tr` background for Chrome and FF:

```
table.header_table tr#row_1 {    
    display:flex;
}
```