# CSS background issue with table row in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-tables

I have a table in which I have this

```
</tr>
<tr class="table-top-background" >
<td class="thread-pic" ></td>
<td class="thread-top-middle"  colspan="2" >Threads</td>
<td class="thread-information">Last Post</td>
</tr>
```

So I want to give background image to my tr, so I put this

```
    .table-top-background

    {
        background:url('/img/design/extra-large-back.png') no-repeat;
        position:relative;
        color:White;
        height:31px;
    }

    .thread-pic
{
   width:30px;
}

.thread-information
{
    width:280px;
}

.thread-top-middle
{
    width:418px;
}
```

The problem is that in all browser's it is fine expect Google Chrome.
In Google Chrome it seems that I give background not to tr, but to all td's... It repeat same background for each td.

It is the same in IE7, but in one of stackoverflow questions I read about solving that with `position:relative` and it helped.
But I didn't find any solutuin for Chrome.
I try to give tr css like this also

```
.table-top-background

{
    background:url('/img/design/extra-large-back.png') no-repeat 0% 100%;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    color:White;
    height:31px;
    width:728px;
}
```

But it change all my table design... At that time text's in td's of this header row aren't in that places and also **all other first td's of my table are in the same size as my header tr** . It seems really hillarious.

I tried also to give `display:inline-table` instead of `display:block` and it didn't help me too...
What is the solution of that problem?

**EDIT:** Same problem is in Safari, so it is webkit problem.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594428/google-chrome-bug-with-tr-background

Answer (score 0):

Although it worked for me, take a look at:

[Can we solve the table row background image problem, in chrome, in multi celled tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997405/can-we-solve-the-table-row-background-image-problem-in-chrome-in-multi-celled)

Which mentions this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pzjUt/

Answer (score 0):

Using display:table-cell on the <tr> seems to do the trick, but it may have side effects in Chrome or other browsers.