# Table background image works in Firefox, but bugs in Chrome

Tags: css

The website for people who want to see it live:
[Click here](http://www.sobafire.com/__v2/?page=browsebuilds)

Bug picture is here: [Bug Picture (JPG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIMa3.jpg)

Basically, I made a table. The first 3 rows in top contains a background image and set a height to 90. Other rows are set to 50 height and contains no background image.

However, although I applied background image to TR, Chrome keeps applying background image on each TD. See the picture, you'll understand.

I've tried several things like moving image to different class or give it additional attributes like no-repeat.

What may be causing and how can I solve it?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594428/google-chrome-bug-with-tr-background

Comment: Should I remove table thing completely and write it with divs? None of the solutions in that topic worked.

Comment: Possibly. Tables are only meant to be used for tabular data. Your data could be called tabular data though so I don't think that tables are the worst solution. ALternatively, as you say, you could use DIVs and it would solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you haven't written the same background-image style for all  class in the CSS?

Try creating an individual class for the first  of the every file and it should work alright.

In addition, as an alternative you can try setting the image as  and putting it background with the position:absolute and then changing z-index although I wouldn't recommend that one.

PD: I wasn't able to check that background-color code on the Website because it wasn't there. (table was different from the one in the picture I mean).