# CSS3 selectors in GChrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have such html structure

```
<tbody>
       <tr rel=0></tr>
</tbody>
```

When page open user can add additional tr tags and structure can be

```
<tbody>
       <tr rel=0></tr>
       <tr rel=1>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
       <tr rel=2>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
       </tr>
</tbody>
```

and i want to add to next tr after tr[rel=0] background image
i use

```
 tr[rel="0"]+tr {
      background:url('{{ asset('../images/home.png') }}') no-repeat 0% 50%;    
 }
```

in FireFox it's working correct, background image appear for  but in GChrome, background image appears in all [td] tags of tr=rel1

How to fix it?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with how each browser handles backgrounds on tr vs td rather than an issue with your selector.

Comment: Why these curly brackets?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594428/google-chrome-bug-with-tr-background